# How to say 'techniques' (as in cooking)

Tags: word-choice

So I need to write a short essay about an interesting experience I had for school and I decided to write about a cooking class I went to.

I'm trying to say

> because I have been to a patisserie class, I did not learn anything new/I did not learn any new techniques.

(The context is dessert making.) But I'm not sure what the right word for 'techniques' is. The word for 'technique' in the dictionary is 手法 but is the context correct for 'cooking techniques' because all the other words that mean 'technique' are very specific.

In terms of the sentence I would like to write this but I'm not sure if it is correct.

> パティスリーのクラスに行ったことがありますから、新しいtechniquesを習いませんでした。

Preferably I would like to say 'I did not learn anything new' but I'm not sure how to form that sentence. Would it be

> 何も新しいを習いませんでした。

Thank you.

Comment: 何も新しいnoun would be better for your second sentence. You have an adjective, but it should be attached to a noun here, I think.

Comment: That's what I thought but I'm not sure what the word for 'techniques' is so I don't know what to say.

Comment: 'I did not learn anything new' would be something like "あまり勉強になりませんでしたが". You could maybe go by こと instead of techniques but I don't know how you could render techniques here in properly in Japanese.

Comment: Thank you. But why is there が at the end of the sentence?

Comment: が at the end of the sentence is here to soften the phrase.

Comment: I guess 調理法 or 調理技術 sounds like culinary arts and  is more specific than 料理の仕方(how to cook)

Comment: I would suggest considering 技｛わざ｝or 技術｛ぎじゅつ｝, or 裏技｛うらわざ｝(special/secret technique).

Comment: 「パティスリーのクラスに行ったことがあったから、新しい｛テクニック/技術｝を習いませんでした。」は意味がわかりにくいです。「｛[前]{まえ}に/[以前]{いぜん}(に)｝お菓子作りの教室に行ったことがあったので、 **今回は**特に新しい｛テクニック/こと｝は[教]{おそ}わりませんでした。」のように、前半と後半の時期が異なることを示した方がいいと思います。

Answer (score -1):

The word you are looking for for "technique" is 技術｛ぎじゅつ}. When you google translate it it comes through as technology, but it has more meanings than that. (https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%8A%80%E8%A1%93-50443)

You can slap 術 on the end of lots of things and mean  techniques. So you could say ベーキング術 to mean baking techniques.

> パティスリーのクラスに行ったことがあったから、新しいベーキング術を習いませんでした。

If you just wanted to say "I didn't learn anything" you would say

> あまり勉強にはなりませんでした。

or

> 何も新しいことを学びませんでした。